# Regular expression split by comma

Tags: regex

I am trying to use this expression:

```
([A-Z])*[=]?([a-z])*, ([A-Z])*[=]?([a-z])*
```

to split the following text:

```
MESSAGE=This , is message., STATUS=400
```

into a comma separated string like this:

```
MESSAGE=This , is message.
STATUS=400
```

Comment: I think you can use `\s*,\s*(?=[A-Z]+=)`, see https://regex101.com/r/UGe1nq/1

Comment: What language are you using here?

Comment: Does it mean you are using Python? Then what is wrong with `re.split(r'\s*,\s*(?=[A-Z]+=)', text)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a programming language, then a regex find all approach might be well suited here.  For example, on Python we can try:

```py
inp = "MESSAGE=This , is message., STATUS=400"
parts = re.findall(r'([A-Z]+\s*=.*?)\s*(?=,\s*[A-Z]+\s*=|$)', inp)
print(parts)  # ['MESSAGE=This , is message.', 'STATUS=400']
```

Answer (score 2):

If your regex engine supports lookaheads you can use

```js
\s*,\s*(?=[A-Z]+=)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UGe1nq/2/).

*Details*:

- `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces on both ends
- `(?=[A-Z]+=)` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there are one or more uppercase ASCII letters and then a `=` sign immediately to the right of the current location.